# Click <div> to expand, then click again to shrink - Its expanding, just not shrinking

Tags: html, expand, shrink

I have a div that expands to show the content once users click onto the div itself.
The div is animated using javascript to it is a little slicker than immediately changing from small to large in a single click.

I have it expanding, just not shrinking again - no matter how much i change the coding.

Clues?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#statExp").click(function(){
    $("#statExp").animate({height:'100px'});    
  });
}); 
</script> 

<div id="statExp" style="background:#98bf21;height:20px;width:450px;position:relative;overflow:hidden;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to keep a boolean around and use it to decide whether to expand or shrink:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
isLarge = false; 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#statExp").click(function(){
    $("#statExp").animate({height:(isLarge ? '20px' : '100px')});
    isLarge = !isLarge;    
  });
}); 
</script> 

<div id="statExp" style="background:#98bf21;height:20px;width:450px;position:relative;overflow:hidden;"></div>
```

Comment: Ah, that worked great. I would never have known how to do that. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

As it has been said then you will need a boolean to remember if it should shrink or expand. This code will remember the initial size. It also allows you to do a little more than just set a single class. It is slightly more extendable.

```
var statHeight;

$(document).ready(function(){
    statHeight = $("#statExp").css('height');
    var toggle = false;
    $("#statExp").click(function(){
        if (!toggle) {
            expand($(this));
            toggle = true;
        } else {
            shrink($(this));
            toggle = false
        }
    });
});

function expand(elem) {
    elem.animate({height:'100px'});
}

function shrink(elem) {
    elem.animate({height:statHeight});
}
```